# SalesForce and Excel - Chrome Extension the Best Solution?

Tags: chrome, microsoft-excel, scraping

I work with a sales team who frequently enter OPPs into SalesForce.

Part of this process requires the sales rep to manually:

1. Google customer City+State to find Zip Codes
2. Use an in-house spreadsheet to map Zip Codes to sales regions
3. Use another spreadsheet to map sales regions to sales reps

This process is done about 100 times/day by my team, and my current idea is to develop a Chrome extension to automate the google + excel spreadsheet lookups.

Any other ideas of how to best solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest converting the spreadsheets to [Google Sheets](https://www.google.com/sheets/about/) and you should be able to automate all of the lookups within the one sheet via the "[Add On](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview)" functionality.